# Как узнать какой объект расположен по заданным координатам (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, monotouch, ios

Как при обработке нажатия определить на какой объект нажал пользователь?
Или как узнать какой объект расположен в заданных координатах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте методы UIView:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

возвращает самую глубокую в иерархии вью, в которую попадает `point`

Например:

```
CGPoint point = somePoint;
UIView* touchedView = [self hitTest:point withEvent:nil];
```

, где `self` - самая внешняя в иерархии вью (например, не обязательно).

и

```
 - (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

возвращает принадлежит ли `point` вью, у которой был вызван этот метод.

В общем, вот [документация](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).